# Can I use SQL CE to provide Membership functionality in WPF desktop application?

Tags: sql, wpf, synchronization, sql-server-ce

I am writing a desktop WPF application that uses SQL CE as its data store and syncs to a remote SQL Server database via a web service. The desktop application provides the same functionality as an ASP.NET web application I wrote but, provides the functionality for the user when no connectivity is available.

The SQL Server database also provides membership functionality for the Web version of the application.

My question is this...how can I provide the user login functionality for the WPF application when it is in "disconnected" mode? I want the user to have the same login functionality that they would have if they were logging in through the web application. I know how to sync the necesarry aspnet_Membership tables (users, roles, etc) but, how do I create the membership provider for WPF? I haven't been able to find examples.

(The WPF app won't need to create or delete users but, edit functionality would be nice...It is essential that application allows the user login and have their password checked against the one synced from the main database so, I am not sure how that encryption/decryption would work).

Thanks for whatever advice you can give

Comment: Membership was built as an ASP.NET feature.   Here is an example where they use Membership outside of ASP.NET.  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/94326/SQL-Express-Membership-API-Provider-Utility.aspx   The risk I see with a local Membership approach is now those tables with passwords are on the local machine and open to being hacked.  The user has to logon at the local machine so the Windows principal is validated.  You might be better off  mapping the Windows logon to roles and groups to provide Membership type features without MembershipService.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Maybe that is the best way to do it...use the User's machine/domain login and map that to the membership information (roles)...It will take some doing but, I could still provide the "Edited by" information when changes are made, then synced to the main database. Thanks for the advice...I was concerned about having everyone's login information (even if encrypted) on each user's local machine. Maybe it is best to avoid that altogether.

Comment: I put it in as as an answer.  Please check it if you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Membership was built as an ASP.NET feature. The risk I see with a local Membership approach is now those tables with passwords are on the local machine and open to being hacked. The user has to logon at the local machine so the Windows principal is validated. You might be better off mapping the Windows logon to roles and groups to provide Membership type features without MembershipService.  You can iterate through the users, roles, and groups in .NET but it is slow.  It is not very hard to decipher the Membership SQL tables directly and build a query to get that information and it is much faster.   You can even map your MembershipProvider to the domain at IIS but then you cannot use TSQL to get the users, roles, and groups.